# Changing color while in a repeat in turtle

Tags: python, colors, repeat, turtle-graphics

I am a python beginner and am working on a basic assignment to write my initials with turtle. I have everything set up with the process of my initials being repeated working properly, however, I need the color to change after each repeat. After extensive research, I could not get it to work. Here is my code.

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(400,400,0,0)

screen.bgcolor('black')

timmy = turtle.Turtle()
timmy.color('orange')

timmy.shape("turtle")

timmy.pencolor("purple")
timmy.pensize(7)

for i in range(0,4):

  timmy.penup()
  timmy.goto(-150,-150)

  timmy.pendown()

  timmy.left(90)
  timmy.forward(150)
  timmy.right(165)
  timmy.forward(155)
  timmy.left(150)
  timmy.forward(155)
  timmy.right(165)
  timmy.forward(150)

  timmy.penup()

  timmy.left(90)
  timmy.forward(30)
  timmy.left(90)

  timmy.pendown()

  timmy.forward(150)
  timmy.backward(75)
  timmy.right(90)
  timmy.forward(50)
  timmy.left(90)
  timmy.forward(75)
  timmy.left(180)
  timmy.forward(150)

  timmy.penup()

  timmy.left(90)
  timmy.forward(30)

  timmy.pendown()
  timmy.left(90)
  timmy.forward(150)
  timmy.right(165)
  timmy.forward(155)
  timmy.left(150)
  timmy.forward(155)
  timmy.right(165)
  timmy.forward(150)
  timmy.left(90)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't reference the `i` variable that controls the number of iterations:

```
timmy.pencolor("purple")

for i in range(0,4):

    ...
```

We can instead do:

```
PEN_COLORS = ["purple", "red", "green", "orange"]

for color in PEN_COLORS:

  timmy.pencolor(color)

  ...
```

Letting the number of colors control the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Right after you start your loop `for i in range(0,4)`, you can add :

```
if i == 0 : timmy.pencolor('NAMEOFCOLOR')
if i == 1 : timmy.pencolor('NAMEOFCOLOR')
if i == 2 : timmy.pencolor('NAMEOFCOLOR')
if i == 3 : timmy.pencolor('NAMEOFCOLOR')
```